# <!DOCTYPE html> breaks margin element

Tags: html, css, doctype

I use `<html>` at the top of my website and the `margin-top: -30px` works fine, but when I use `<!DOCTYPE html>` it breaks my margin so I can't use the margin option to move my button.

Heres the code so you can have a closer look:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>Västerås Bastuklubb</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <style type="text/css">
    .classname {
        -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bee2f9;
        -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bee2f9;
        box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bee2f9;
        background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #63b8ee), color-stop(1, #468ccf) );
        background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #63b8ee 5%, #468ccf 100% );
        filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#63b8ee', endColorstr='#468ccf');
        background-color:#63b8ee;
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius:42px;
        -moz-border-radius-topleft:42px;
        border-top-left-radius:42px;
        -webkit-border-top-right-radius:42px;
        -moz-border-radius-topright:42px;
        border-top-right-radius:42px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:42px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomright:42px;
        border-bottom-right-radius:42px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:42px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:42px;
        border-bottom-left-radius:42px;
        text-indent:0px;
        border:1px solid #3866a3;
        display:inline-block;
        color:#14396a;
        font-family:Arial;
        font-size:15px;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-style:normal;
        height:22px;
        line-height:22px;
        width:22px;
        text-decoration:none;
        text-align:center;
        text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #7cacde;
    }
    .classname:hover {
        background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #468ccf), color-stop(1, #63b8ee) );
        background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #468ccf 5%, #63b8ee 100% );
        filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#468ccf', endColorstr='#63b8ee');
        background-color:#468ccf;
    }.classname:active {
        position:relative;
        top:1px;
    }</style>

        <style>
        *{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        body, html
        {
            width: 100%;
            font-family: Open sans;
            font-size: 14x;
        }
        body{
            background-image: url('http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/tree_bark.png');
        }
        #header
        {
            background-image: url('http://ipad.iwalls.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/pouring_water_ipad_wallpaper_png-1024x1024.jpg');
            height: 100px;
            background-position: -200px;
            background-position-y: -600px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-color: #FFF;
            border: 3px solid #CCC;
            margin: 0px auto;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 40px;
            padding-top: 30px;
        }

        .content
        {
            padding-top: 20px;
            padding-left: 20px;
        }

        #footer
        {
            background-image: url('http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/binding_dark.png');
            height: 52px;
            margin-top: 435px;
            opacity: 0.9;
        }

        #footer-content
        {
            float: left;
            color: #fff;
            padding-left: 20px;
            padding-top: 15px;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
        #footer-widget
        {
            float: right;
            padding-right: 30px;
            padding-top: 15px;
        }
        #footer-widget a
        {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #fff;
        }
        #signup{
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            background-image: url('http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/greyzz.png');
            display: none;
            margin-left: 500px;
            margin-top: 150px;
            border: 2px solid #000;
            text-align: center;
        }
        #contact
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 500px;
            height: 400px;
            background-image: url('http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/greyzz.png');
            display: none;
            margin-left: 500px;
            margin-top: 150px;
            border: 3px solid #000;
            text-align: center;
        }


        #about
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 500px;
            height: 400px;
            background-image: url('http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/greyzz.png');
            display: none;
            margin-left: 500px;
            margin-top: 150px;
            border: 3px solid #000;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #signup button{
            margin-left: 385px;
            margin-top: -30px;
        }
        #contact button
        {
            margin-left: 385px;
            margin-top: -30px;
        }
        #about button
        {
            margin-left: 385px;
            margin-top: -30px;
        }
        #signup-content{
            font-size: 12px;

        }
        #contact-content
        {

        }
        #about-content{
            width: 250px;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-family: Verdana;
            padding-top: 40px;
            text-align: center;
            padding-left: 30px;
        }
        </style>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#sign').click(function(){
                    $('#signup').show({
                        'autoopen': true
                    });
                });
            });

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#om').click(function(){
                    $('#about').show({
                        'autoopen': true
                    });
                });
            });

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#kontakta').click(function(){
                    $('#contact').show({
                        'autoopen': true
                    });
                });
            });

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('button').click(function() {
                    $('#signup').hide(200);
                    $('#contact').hide(200);
                    $('#about').hide(200);q
                });
            });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="signup">
            <p>ANMÄLAN</p>
            <button type="button" class="classname">X</button>
        </div>
        <div id="contact">
            <p>KONTAKTA OSS</p>
            <button type="button" class="classname">X</button>
        </div>
        <div id="about">
            <p>OM OSS</p>
            <button type="button" class="classname">X</button>
            <div id="about-content">
            <p>Västerås basuklubb är en ideel förening som jobbar för att främja bastbadet i Västerås med omnejd. Vi är idag över 100 medlemmar som tycker att bastu är det absolut bästa som finns.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="header">
            <p>VÄSTERÅS BASTUKLUBB</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <ul>
            <p>YOLO SWAG</p>
        </ul>
        </div>
            <div id="footer">
                <div id="footer-content"><p>VÄSTERÅS BASTUKLUBB - (C) 2013</p></div>
                <div id="footer-widget">
                    <a href="#kontakta-oss" id="kontakta">KONTAKTA OSS |</a>    
                    <a href="#om-oss" id="om">OM OSS |</a>
                    <a href="#anmalan" id="sign">ANMÄLAN</a>
                </div>
            </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

apparently this fixed it:

```
    #signup button{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 185px;
    margin-top: -35px;
}
```

don't know why postion: absolute; fixes the problem.

edit postion element breaks the jQuery script. I guess that I'll have to go without a doctype.

Comment: Without anything for use to see what you are trying to do is not helping yourself or anyone... Maybe trying making a fiddle so we can see your problem (http://jsfiddle.net/). `<!DOCTYPE html>` is declaring to the web browser that this is an html document. Like the below answer, you should have that first, then a <html>, then a `<head>` followed by a `</head>`, then `<body>`, and the closing tags `</body>` / `</html>`

Comment: Please share the HTML code.

Comment: its creepy how u structure ur script

Comment: You guys do know that I can code HTML and CSS, It's just something weird with this since I have done other webpages the same way. Well I've edited my first post, and you can take a look at the actual code.

Comment: Is the negative margin issue fixed? or did I misunderstand this question?

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't mean you're doing it well.  Otherwise, why are you here?

Comment: The issue seems to be fixed for now, thanks for the help guys. Added the solution to the main post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<!DOCTYPE html>` should be used on top. Below the `<!DOCTYPE>` comes the `<html>` tag.

Comment: The start tag for the HTML element is (by specification) optional (the element is included implicitly). Adding one won't make a difference.

Comment: Did this fix the negative margin issue?

Answer (score 0):

Different doctypes effect the way css is rendered in the browser.  Stick to the `<!DOCTYPE html>`, and then make adjustments to your html and css to position your content.  For example, see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/curlybraces/FDCtz/.  Try changing the margin from -30px to just 30px, and you'll see how the button moves up or down depending on that change.

Comment: I know dude, but I'm trying to move my button to the upper right corner and using marigin-top dosen't work. -left,-right works

Comment: then try positioning.  see this new fiddle (a fork off the previous one): http://jsfiddle.net/curlybraces/6VN9W/2/

Answer (score 0):

If your page works without `<!DOCTYPE html>`, just don’t add it. Apparently your page now works in [Quirks Mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html) (to the extent that anything really *works* in that mode), so why bother breaking it? Changing a page to work in Standards Mode should be expected to be a major effort, comparable to rewriting the page.

Answer (score -1):

`<!DOCTYPE html>` Is a document format declaration for your web browser.  Older versions of HTML had specific formatting standards that could be used, depending on what type `!DOCTYPE` you were declaring.

Furthermore, a lot of designers perform a CSS reset to all standard HTML elements:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

OR, simply:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```